# prevent firefox page state caching

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, caching

How do i prevent firefox from caching page state? I'm developing a web app and firefox is automatically setting previously checked checkboxes without triggering any events. Is there a way to prevent firefox from doing this or do I just have to reset my entire ui on startup with js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `autocomplete="off"` to the afflicted fields, [MDN Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/how_to_turn_off_form_autocompletion). If that doesn't work and you can use jQuery I would go with `$(form).reset()` on page load as an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to set the HTTP Expires header to be expired, that way Firefox won't cache the page, it'll go back to the server.

In PHP you can do this by calling:

```
  header("Expires: 0");
```